# how to store two variables strings in 2d array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm working with multi-dimensional arrays in PHP. I want to store two string values in a two dimensional array. I have tried the following code:

```
$arr[][]=['string1']['string2'];
```

I have also tried:

```
$arr[][]="string1","string2";
```

Due to the comma I have a syntax error.
How can I fix this?

Comment: And what result do you expect?

Comment: You need to show expected, but `$arr[][]=["string1","string2"];`

Comment: @u_mulder i want to store these strings in 2D array.

Comment: What do you __consider__ a 2D array?

Comment: I want to have result like $arr['string1]['string2']

Comment: So, `$arr['string1]['string2'] = 42` then?

Comment: Its a simple thing one is key and other is value. I will get it by $arr[key][value].

Comment: No bro this is different thing what i want to do is that i want to store one string as key and string 2 is value.

Comment: Then you need to do this `$arr[]['string1'] = 'string 2' ;`

Answer (score 3):

```
$arr = [];
$arr[] = ['string1'];
$arr[] = ['string2'];

// or simply
// $arr = [['string1'], ['string2']];

print_r($arr);

// output:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => string1 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => string2 ) )
```

If you want `'string1'` and `'string2'` to be the key and subkey in an array then you use:

```
$arr = [];
$arr['string1']['string2'] = 'somevalue';
```